# Need help styling a content strip in both dekstop and device

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a responsive strip in my Wordpress and I am rather struggling. I have provided two screenshots to help:

For Desktop, it's looking ok but I am having the following issues:
1: When I increase the padding of the button to make it same height as the input field, it shifts the input field, meaning they're never aligned and I don't know how to fix that?
2: Apply extra width to the input field, when I try to add width, the width increases from left to right, overlapping the button
3: When I attempt to move the container containing the input field and button more to the left (see class .lnviXl.lnviXl) in css, the input field shrinks. Not shown on screenshot

[image]

Device:

In devices it looks bad. Simply, I want the gif and text to be next each other and below is an input field and below that the button. Here is what it looks like on a shruken desktop screen to try and replicate a device. Also what's weird, I can't see this text field and button in my mobile device (only can see the image and text) but yer when I shrink browser screen on desktop to replicate device preview, I can see the input field and button. Really bizzare

[image]

Here is the current code:

```css
/*newsletter section */

#custom_html-4 {
  width: 100% !important;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
}

.eVEmvD.eVEmvD.eVEmvD.eVEmvD.eVEmvD.eVEmvD {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}

.newsletter_section {
  width: 100% !important;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: black;
}

.newsletter_text_section {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  margin-left: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.newsletter_text_section p {
  font-size: 24px !important;
  margin: 0;
  color: black !important;
}

.newsletter_gif {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.newsletter_input_section {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.klaviyo-form-Rrsqsh {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.kvTDNe.kvTDNe {
  width: 400px;
}

.lnviXl.lnviXl {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-align: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 200px;
}

@media(max-width: 855px) {
  .newsletter_section {
    display: block;
  }
  .newsletter_input_section {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
    clear: both;
    width: 100% !important;
    display: block !important;
  }
  .newsletter_text_section {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .fGCWnQ.fGCWnQ {
    padding: 0px !important;
  }
  .ctaEzx.ctaEzx {
    max-width: none !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<aside id="custom_html-4" class="widget_text widget_number_8 column-1_5 widget widget_custom_html">
  <div class="textwidget custom-html-widget">
    <div class="newsletter_section">
      <div class="newsletter_text_section">
        <img src="..." class="newsletter_gif">
        <p>Join Balance and get 20% off your first order</p>
      </div>
      <div class="newsletter_input_section">
        <div class="klaviyo-form-Rrsqsh klaviyo-form form-version-cid-3">
          <div>
            <form class="needsclick View__FormView-sc-1ou3cq2-0 ctaEzx klaviyo-form-version-cid_3 kl-private-reset-css-Xuajs1" novalidate="" isembed="true" tabindex="-1">
              <div class="needsclick Column__FormColumn-z5j99u-0 hVFNhP kl-private-reset-css-Xuajs1">
                <div data-testid="form-row" class="needsclick Row__FormRow-sc-17nghml-0 lnviXl kl-private-reset-css-Xuajs1">
                  <div component="[object Object]" formcomponentstyling="[object Object]" data-testid="form-component" class="needsclick FormComponent__StyledFormComponentWrapper-e0xun6-0 CWZcV notranslate kl-private-reset-css-Xuajs1" formcomponenttheme="[object Object]">
                    <div class="needsclick TextInput__StyledInputContainer-sc-1o6de9f-1 kvTDNe kl-private-reset-css-Xuajs1">
                      <input type="email" name="email" tabindex="0" styling="[object Object]" placeholder="enter email" aria-label="enter email" aria-invalid="true" valid="0" options="[object Object]" class="notranslate needsclick TextInput__FormStyledTextInput-sc-1o6de9f-0 eFCYcA kl-private-reset-css-Xuajs1"
                        aria-describedby="klaviyo_ariaid_6">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div component="[object Object]" fullwidth="true" formcomponentstyling="[object Object]" data-testid="form-component" class="needsclick FormComponent__StyledFormComponentWrapper-e0xun6-0 fGCWnQ notranslate kl-private-reset-css-Xuajs1" formcomponenttheme="[object Object]"><button type="button" tabindex="0" class="needsclick Button__FormStyledButton-p2mbjt-0 eVEmvD kl-private-reset-css-Xuajs1">JOIN NOW</button></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" class="notranslate needsclick View__HiddenSubmit-sc-1ou3cq2-1 StXTa kl-private-reset-css-Xuajs1" value="Submit">
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</aside>
```

Comment: Please make sure you have the code exactly as you have shown in the image.

Comment: Your code looks really large for me to go through at the moment, but instead of using float, please checkout CSS Flex. => https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/